# Numerical solution to 2D nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am struggling to numerically solve the second-order nonlinear PDE for $f(x_1, x_2)$ of the form:
$$0 = f + f^2 + f_1 + f_2 + f_{11} + f_{22}$$
I tried several functions from Matlab and Mathematica, but none of them seem suited for my equation. $x_1 \text{ and } x_2$ represent spacial dimensions.

My reference suggests to solve it by approximating the function $f(x_1, x_2)$ with Chebyshev polynomials, which is probably going to take me couple of days to code it by hand. Is it possible to solve this PDE with built-in functions from Matlab, Mathematica or other software?

Comment: What are the domain and the boundary conditions?

Comment: This is another problem. The paper, which introduces this PDE, does not specify the boundary conditions. After I will know that some method allows to solve this PDE I will play a little bit with boundary conditions, trying to guess reasonable values.

Comment: It is obviously not going to be very well posed without boundary conditions..

Comment: In general, it will be something like $x_1 \in [a,b]$, $x_2 \in [c,d]$, and boundary conditions for $f(a,0)$, $f(b,0)$, $f(0,c)$, $f(0,d)$, where $a, c <0$, $b,d >0$.

Comment: Mathematica has the function `NDSolve`, which solves PDEs in two variables with boundary conditions on rectangular regions.

Comment: I tried to use NDSolve and kept getting "Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.". The previous threads here suggest that the current version of NDSolve can not handle nonlinear PDEs.

Comment: You can also use perturbation theory by multiplying the $f^2$ term by a constant $g$ which you set equal to $1$ at the end of the calculations. You then write $f$ as $$f = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g^kf^{(k)}$$ which yields linear PDEs for each term of the perturbation series.